# Flash crashes when stopping directshow source filter

Tags: c++, flash, crash, directshow

Here's the callstack :

> 0480b000()
>        vcam.ax!CSourceStream::DoBufferProcessingLoop()  + 0xe1 bytes
>        vcam.ax!CSourceStream::ThreadProc()  + 0x13e bytes
>        vcam.ax!CAMThread::InitialThreadProc()  + 0x51 bytes
>        kernel32.dll!7c80b713()

The callstack is from this thread:

```
0    >    0x000015b8    Worker Thread    CAMThread::InitialThreadProc    0480b000    Normal    0
```

disassembly code:

```
017D0B5B  push        edx 
017D0B5C  mov         eax,dword ptr [ecx+8]
017D0B5F  call        eax 
017D0B61  cmp         esi,esp
017D0B63  call        @ILT+2525(__RTC_CheckEsp) (17C49E2h)
017D0B68  cmp         dword ptr [ebp-2Ch],0
017D0B6C  je          CSourceStream::DoBufferProcessingLoop+10Ah (17D0B8Ah)
017D0B6E  mov         eax,dword ptr [ebp-2Ch]
```

Problem exists at the line `017D0B5F  call        eax`

This problem exists for most directshow filters ,how to fix?

Answer (score 0):

I believe vcam.ax's source code is [here](http://tmhare.mvps.org/downloads/vcam.zip), so probably the best option is to compile the source code locally and then attach to the process that's crashing in the debugger.  Then you can put a breakpoint in the DoBufferProcessingLoop() implementation, recreate the crash, and you should be able figure out why you're crashing.

Answer (score 0):

I'v used vcom.ax and encountered the same problem as yours. I solve it by following step.
Add `CAutoLock cAutoLock(&m_cSharedState);` on the first Line of following function:

- `CVCamStream::CVCamStream()  //constructor`
- `CVCamStream::~CVCamStream() //distructor`
- `HRESULT CVCamStream::FillBuffer(IMediaSample *pms)`
- `HRESULT CVCamStream::OnThreadCreate()`

This may solve your problem.